# Narrow down results with SQL joins?

Tags: sql, hsqldb

I'm new to SQL and I have three tables:

```
ALBUMS
album_id | album_name | artist_id | category_id

CATEGORIES
category_id | category_name

ARTISTS
artist_id | artist_name
```

given a `category_name`, how can i get a result set of `category_id, album_id, album_name, artist_id, artist_name`?

I've tried many variations of JOIN, but I keep ending up with MORE results, not narrowing of results. Is this even possible?

Comment: What database do you use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select ALBUMS.category_id
,      ALBUMS.album_id
,      ALBUMS.album_name
,      ALBUMS.artist_id
,      ARTISTS.artist_name
from   ALBUMS
       inner join ARTISTS on ALBUMS.artist_id = ARTISTS.artist_id
       inner join CATEGORIES on ALBUMS.category_id = CATEGORIES .category_id
where  CATEGORIES.category_name = 'Your category name'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want category "abc" do like this

```
Select a.category_id, a.album_id, c.album_name, a.artist_id, a.artist_name
from ALBUMS a
join CATEGORIES b on a.category_id=b.category_id
join ARTISTS c on a.artist_id =c.artist_id
where c.Categoryname='abc'
```

Comment: Not say thank you. If it is help out then right mark